# Custom Primary Key in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I created a class:

```
class Incident extends Model {

    use EventGenerator;

    protected $table = 'incidents';
    protected $primaryKey = "incident_id";
    protected $fillable = ['incident_id', 'incident_type', 'location', 'street', 'city', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'date', 'time', 'incident_archived'];
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function set($data) {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $this->{$key} = $value;
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function responders() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Classes\Responder');
    }

    public function incidentTypes() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\IncidentType', 'incident_incident_type', 'incident_id');
    }

    // set fields on the eloquent object and save to database
    // raise event that the incident was created.
    public function createIncident($command) {
        $this->incident_id = $command->incidentId;
        $this->save();
        $this->raise(new IncidentWasPosted($this));
        return $this;
    }
}
```

The primary key should be a custom one `incident_id`. Thats why I set the property. Still when I use tinker to create an object like this:

```
$incident = new \App\Incident
$incident->incident_id = "I100"
$incident->save()
$incident->incidentTypes()->attach("AED")
```

and want to use the attach() method, I get the error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]:
>   Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row:
>   a foreign key constraint fails (`homestead`.`incident_incident_type`,
>   CONSTRAINT `incident_incident_type_incident_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`incident_id`) REFERENCES `incidents` (`incident_id`)) (SQL: insert
>   into `incident_incident_type` (`incident_id`, `incident_type_id`)
>   values (0, AED))'

**Question**

Why is the value being added to the SQL statement still "0" and not "I100" like I added it? as this is the valid PK and not 0 (which would be the default "id" field as a PK.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around what you are trying to achieve, but your setup is very confusing. You have an `incident_id` and `incident_type` in your `incidents` table and you have a `incident_id` and `incident_type_id` in your `incident_types` table? Then you also have pivot table called `incident_incident_type` with another `incident_id` and `incident_type_id`?

Comment: What is the column type for incident_id? If it's an int, and you're passing a string, it's going to get converted to a 0

Answer (score 0):

If you have confirmed that the initial $incident->save() is working correctly by saving the correct data to your database, try a dd() immediately after to see the current state of $incident:

```
dd($incident->incident_id);
```

Based on what you're reporting, this value should output as '0' or null. If that's the case, try:

```
$incident = $incident->save();
```

Repeat the dd(), and hopefully you'll see the correct value.

If, in fact, your incident is *not* saving to the database correctly. You will need to try guard/reguard to make your primary key assignable:

```
$incident->unguard();
$incident->incident_id = "I100";
$incident->reguard();
```